# Infopath with sharepoint: Retrieval of the XML document from the following location is not authorized:

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I am deploying a form in sharepoint library. When I open the form it is working but when i open the saved form the it shows an error Retrieval of the XML document from the following location is not authorized: and then form is closed. Please help me.

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you working with? Did you check MOSS's log files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is due to server problem, and i dont know about it. Now it is ok!